# QToolButton looks ugly

Tags: macos, qt

On Mac OS X QToolButton looks ugly. How to apply QPushButton style to QToolButton? I use menu button popup mode. QPushButton hasn't such mode. So just to use QPushButton is not a decision.

[image: QPushButton and QToolButton on Mac OS X]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks ugly because OS X doesn't have such a native control, so the mac style has to approximate something. You'd have to implement a proxy style that draws this control differently, perhaps redirecting to pushbutton's appearance and overdrawing a line and a triangle.